# JavaScript - Search on formatted numbers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am showing numbers formatted with comma in my AngularJs app using number filter with a directive to highlight the searched string in the results.

Code:

```
if (phrase) text = text.replace(new RegExp('('+phrase+')', 'gi'), '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>');
```

When the user types 123, I need to show **1,23**,456. It messes up when encounters a comma..

Is there any regexp to achieve this? or any inbuilt angular way..?
Here's the [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/h8xPtBbraqIE65yOgtLE?p=preview)

Comment: `I need to show 1,23,456`. Why? This would be wrong. It should be 123,456.

Comment: I am not seeing an issue in your Plunker.  I type 13144 and it filters correctly to 13,144.

Comment: @dustmouse - the filter works fine..I need to highlight the searched string...

Comment: @ManoDestra - the original string should be as it is..

Comment: Ah, see what you're saying. That's not actually a number. It's text. Would have been better with a text based example, rather than a numeric one, as that's not a valid number format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your highlight-filter to this (add ',?' for each char in `phrase`):

```
angular.module('AngApp')
.filter('highlight', function($sce) {
  return function(text, phrase) {
    if(typeof(text) != 'string') text = text.toString();
    if (phrase) {
      var regexp = '';
      for(var i = 0; i < phrase.length; i++) {
        regexp += phrase[i] + ',?';
      }
      text = text.replace(new RegExp('('+regexp+')', 'gi'),
      '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>')
    }

    return $sce.trustAsHtml(text)
  }
});
```

Updated [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/mv7tVEUSTazinOOYB2GU?p=preview)

Comment: @PremshankarTiwari No problem, please upvote also if this helped :).